# Insert template table (at table tool->design) to outlook mail by VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I tried to create table in outlook email by using VBA. I know that we can use Htmlbody with table tab to create table. Something like below code

```
Sub Test  
    Set oolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email = oolApp.CreateItem(0)

    Dim MailBody As String
    MailBody = "<table border=1>"
    MailBody = MailBody & "<tr><td>" & "aaa" & "</td>" & "<td>" & "bbb" & "</td>" & "<td>" & "bbb" & "</td></tr>"
    MailBody = MailBody & "<tr><td>" & "123" & "</td>" & "<td>" & "456" & "</td>" & "<td>" & "789" & "</td></tr>"
    MailBody = MailBody & "</table>"

    Email.HTMLBody = MailBody

    Email.display   

End Sub
```

But I would like to use template table in Table Tool -> Design to make table more beautiful. Is there anyway to do it with VBA code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead, create the table manually and save as an .oft file.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ThreeColumnGreenStripeTable

    Dim Email as mailitem
    Set Email = CreateItemFromTemplate("path to ThreeColumnGreenStripeTable.oft")
    Email.display   

End Sub
```

Comment: That sound a good idea. But thank for your answer. I finnaly decide to use html to create table. because I can do more thing for my table with it. However, your idea still a good way to achieve and thanks so much for your help